# Change WPF treeViewItem Background color when selected but lost focus

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I am trying to change a TreeViewItem background color when it selected but lost focus.
I saw some similar questions like:
[WPF TreeViewItem Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499962/wpf-treeviewitem-background)
, but I couldn't use it...

Here is my tree view Xaml code:

```
>     <UserControl x:Class="Ednfi.Setup.Presentation.Views.TreeViewViews.StationTree"
> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
> xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
> xmlns:behaviour="clr-namespace:Ednfi.Setup.Presentation.Extensions;assembly=Ednfi.Setup.Presentation"
> xmlns:nodes="clr-namespace:Ednfi.Setup.Presentation.ViewModels.TreeViewViewModels.Nodes"
> mc:Ignorable="d"
> xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
> xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
> d:DesignHeight="226" d:DesignWidth="227"
> xmlns:ml="clr-namespace:Ednfi.Setup.Presentation.ml_resources">
>         <TreeView Margin="10 0 10 20" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Root.Children}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
> VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
>     
>     
>             <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
>                 <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
>                     <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
>                     <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
>                 </Style>
>             </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
>             <TreeView.Resources>
>                 <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
>                     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
>                     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment,
> RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
> />
>                     <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment,
> RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
> />
>                     <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,0,0,0" />
>                     <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
>                     <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
>                     <Setter Property="behaviour:TreeViewItemBehavior.IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected"
> Value="True" />
>                     <Setter Property="Template">
>                         <Setter.Value>
>                             <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
>                                 <Grid>
>                                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>                                         <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto" />
>                                         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
>                                         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
>                                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>                                     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
>                                         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
>                                         <RowDefinition />
>                                     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
>                                     <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
> TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press" />
>                                     <Border Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Selection_Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
> BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
> BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
> Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
>                                         <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
> x:Name="PART_Header" ContentSource="Header" />
>                                     </Border>
>                                     <ItemsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ItemsHost" />
>                                 </Grid>
>                                 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
>                                     <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
>                                         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ItemsHost" />
>                                     </Trigger>
>                                     <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
>                                         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" TargetName="Expander" />
>                                     </Trigger>
>                                     <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
>                                         <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"
> TargetName="Selection_Border" />
>                                         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static
> SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
>                                     </Trigger>
>                                     <MultiTrigger>
>                                         <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
>                                             <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
>                                             <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false" />
>                                         </MultiTrigger.Conditions>                                    
>                                         <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"
> TargetName="Selection_Border" />                                    
>                                         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static
> SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
>                                     </MultiTrigger>
>                                     <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
>                                         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
>                                     </Trigger>
>                                 </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
>                             </ControlTemplate>
>                         </Setter.Value>
>                     </Setter>
>                 </Style>
>                 <!-- Style for the ToggleButton control used to expand/collapse a TreeViewItem control -->
>                 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
>                     <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
>                     <Setter Property="Width" Value="19" />
>                     <Setter Property="Height" Value="13" />
>                     <Setter Property="Template">
>                         <Setter.Value>
>                             <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
>                                 <Border Width="19" Height="13" Background="#00FFFFFF" x:Name="Border">
>                                     <Border Width="9" Height="9" x:Name="Border1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" BorderBrush="#FF9495A2"
> BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="1,1,1,1">
>                                         <Border.Background>
>                                             <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
>                                                 <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.4" />
>                                                 <GradientStop Color="#FFC6CEDA" Offset="1" />
>                                             </LinearGradientBrush>
>                                         </Border.Background>
>                                         <Path Fill="#FF000000" Margin="1,1,1,1" x:Name="ExpandPath" Data="M0,2L0,3 2,3 2,5 3,5 3,3
> 5,3 5,2 3,2 3,0 2,0 2,2z" />
>                                     </Border>
>                                 </Border>
>                                 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
>                                     <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
>                                         <Setter Property="Data" Value="M0,2L0,3 5,3 5,2z" TargetName="ExpandPath" />
>                                     </Trigger>
>                                 </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
>                             </ControlTemplate>
>                         </Setter.Value>
>                     </Setter>
>                 </Style>
>                 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type nodes:MonitorNode}">
>                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 2 0 0">
>                         <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0 0 3 0" />
>                         <TextBlock Text="{x:Static ml:MultiLang._157}" x:Name="ML_0048" />
>                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
>                         <TextBlock Text="{x:Static ml:MultiLang._158}" x:Name="ML_0050" />
>                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
>                     </StackPanel>
>                 </DataTemplate>
>                 <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type nodes:StationNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
>                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 2 0 0">
>                         <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
>                             <ContextMenu HasDropShadow="True">
>                                 <MenuItem Header="{x:Static ml:MultiLang._160}" Command="{Binding CopyMonitorsCommand}"
> x:Name="ML_0055" />
>                                 <MenuItem Header="{x:Static ml:MultiLang._159}" Command="{Binding PasteMonitorsCommand}"
> x:Name="ML_0056" />
>                                 <MenuItem Header="{x:Static ml:MultiLang._162}" Command="{Binding CopyStationsCommand}"
> x:Name="ML_0057" />
>                                 <MenuItem Header="{x:Static ml:MultiLang._161}" Command="{Binding PasteStationsCommand}"
> x:Name="ML_0058" />
>                             </ContextMenu>
>                         </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
>                         <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0 0 3 0" />
>                         <TextBlock Text="{x:Static ml:MultiLang._157}" x:Name="ML_0060" />
>                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
>                         <TextBlock Text="{x:Static ml:MultiLang._158}" x:Name="ML_0062" />
>                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
>                     </StackPanel>
>                 </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
>                 <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type nodes:FilteringNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
>                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 2 0 0">
>                         <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0 0 3 0" />
>                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
>                     </StackPanel>
>                 </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
>             </TreeView.Resources>
>         </TreeView>
>     </UserControl>
```

The current background color looks blue when selected.

But when still selected, but lost focus the background color is gray.

I just want it to stay blue !!!
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In default template of `TreeViewItem`, there is MultiDataTrigger which set the color to `ControlBrushKey` when item is not in focus which you can override in your TreeView resources like this:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
      <Style.Resources>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                       Color="#FF3399FF"/>
      </Style.Resources>
      ...
   </Style>
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

then there is no need to override ControlTemplate of TreeViewItem.

But, however it also set text of treeViewItem to `ControlTextBrushKey` which by default is black. So, with only `ControlBrushKey` overriden, you will get it work like this:

**Without Focus**:

[image]

**With Focus**

[image]

As you can see brush is over-ridden properly but if you override `ControlTextBrushKey` and set it to white than treeView Item's won't be visible since controlTextBrush will be set to white.

---

However, in case you want exact same look of TreeViewItem like it has with focus, you have to override control template and remove that MultiDataTrigger from the default template.

Default template will go like this:

```
    <TreeView>
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="19" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ToggleButton IsChecked="False"
                                              ClickMode="Press"
                                              Name="Expander">
                                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                            <Style.Resources>
                                                <ResourceDictionary />
                                            </Style.Resources>
                                            <Setter Property="UIElement.Focusable" Value="False"/>
                                            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Width" Value="16"/>
                                            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Height" Value="16"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                                        <Border Padding="5,5,5,5"
                                                                Background="#00FFFFFF"
                                                                Width="16"
                                                                Height="16">
                                                            <Path Fill="#FFFFFFFF"
                                                                  Stroke="#FF818181"
                                                                  Name="ExpandPath">
                                                                <Path.Data>
                                                                    <PathGeometry Figures="M0,0L0,6L6,0z" />
                                                                </Path.Data>
                                                                <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="135" CenterX="3" CenterY="3" />
                                                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                                                            </Path>
                                                        </Border>
                                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                                <Setter Property="UIElement.RenderTransform" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                                        <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterX="3" CenterY="3" />
                                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                                </Setter>
                                                                <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                                        <SolidColorBrush>#FF595959</SolidColorBrush>
                                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                                </Setter>
                                                                <Setter Property="Shape.Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                                        <SolidColorBrush>#FF262626</SolidColorBrush>
                                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                                </Setter>
                                                            </Trigger>
                                                            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                                <Setter Property="Shape.Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                                        <SolidColorBrush>#FF27C7F7</SolidColorBrush>
                                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                                </Setter>
                                                                <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                                        <SolidColorBrush>#FFCCEEFB</SolidColorBrush>
                                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                                </Setter>
                                                            </Trigger>
                                                            <MultiTrigger>
                                                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                    <Condition Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                                                    <Condition Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                                                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                <Setter Property="Shape.Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                                        <SolidColorBrush>#FF1CC4F7</SolidColorBrush>
                                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                                </Setter>
                                                                <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                                        <SolidColorBrush>#FF82DFFB</SolidColorBrush>
                                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                                </Setter>
                                                            </MultiTrigger>
                                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ToggleButton.Style>
                                </ToggleButton>
                                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                                        Name="Bd"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                        Grid.Column="1">
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.Header}"
                                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate}"
                                                      ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderedItemsControl.HeaderStringFormat}"
                                                      ContentSource="Header"
                                                      Name="PART_Header"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                </Border>
                                <ItemsPresenter Name="ItemsHost"
                                                Grid.Column="1"
                                                Grid.Row="1"
                                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.HasItems" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Hidden"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Bd">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" />
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" />
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}" />
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item1"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item2"/>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: It worked !!!!!! Thank you very much !!! I don't have enough reputation to vote up for you. Sorry....

Comment: No problem S.K. Glad to help..!!

Comment: P.S, I got over the foregroud color issue by painting it black when selected.

Comment: this works for me (as far a the color goes) except the toggle button won't open the item anymore. :-(

Comment: So I changed the IsChecked on the ToggleButton to IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" and now it's working.

Answer (score 35):

In reference to this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14912591/1013377), the `ControlBrushKey` did not work for me. The `InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey` did, however. Also setting the `InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey` got around the changing text color.

My complete solution:

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <!-- Style the inactive selection the same as active -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"
                     Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}"
                     Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextColorKey}}"/>
</TreeView.Resources>
```