# Change WPF's ListBoxItem Background when it's selected and Window lost focus

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem, mahapps.metro

I was working on a Study project using [MahApps:Metro](http://mahapps.com/) (don't know if it's relevant) when I got stuck in the following problem:

Is there a way of change the `Background` of a `ListBoxItem` **only** when it's selected and the `Window` loses focus?

See the following images to ilustrate:

[image: Image number one]

Here we can see my ListBox with the first item selected when the window **has** focus.

[image: Image number two]

And on this second image we can see how it looks like when the focus is on the `Window` number two.

I would like to know if there's a way of changing the Blue `Background` of the `SelectedItem` to a LightGray, for example, **only** when the Window loses focus.

Here's what I've looked so far:

- Overwrite `ControlBrushKey` (actually kind of works, but replaces the style when the window has focus) [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606281/change-wpf-treeviewitem-background-color-when-selected-but-lost-focus) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462232/selected-item-loses-style-when-focus-moved-out-in-wpf-listbox) [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382006/wpf-listview-inactive-selection-color/382162#382162)
- Overwrite `HighlightBrushKey`(same problem) [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138200/change-background-color-for-selected-listbox-item/2138237#2138237)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently only possible if you override the `ListBoxItem` style by yourself (I'll change this in the next releases of MahApps).

This is what you need:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource GrayBrush7}" />
</MultiTrigger>
```

Complete style:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomMetroListBoxItem"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroListBoxItem}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Border"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource AccentSelectedColorBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush3}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource GrayBrush7}" />
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource GrayBrush7}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource AccentSelectedColorBrush}" />
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource GrayBrush7}" />
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush2}" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomMetroListBoxItem}"
         Style="{StaticResource VirtualisedMetroListBox}" />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Below example solves your problem.
Note the `MultiDataTrigger`.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        <Grid Width="200" Background="Lime">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Black"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate2">
        <Grid Width="200" Background="DarkGray">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Black"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1Sel">
        <Grid Width="200" Background="Coral">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Black"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox x:Name="Lst" Margin="0,56,10,0">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource DataTemplate1Sel}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource DataTemplate1}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition  Binding="{Binding IsActive, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition  Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource DataTemplate2}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

[image: Output]